# Proper use of a side inlet elbow in bathroom DWV situation

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I'm renovating a 2nd floor bathroom in a 95 year old house. I'm not changing the layout much except for replacing the existing standard toilet with a wall toilet and slightly changing the location of the tub drain (different size tub). Because the cast iron pipe is 95 years old, I figured it would be best to replace it now while everything is opened up. I'm replacing everything down to where the cast iron tees into the horizontal sewer line in the slab in my basement.

Although the layout is not changed much, I don't think the current configuration of cast iron meets code (I'm in New York State). The tub drain has a horizontal vent below flood line of the tub, and it ties into the toilet drain between the toilet and the toilet's horizontal wet vent (wet vent is lav drain). Basically I'm going to change the tub vent so it's vertical, in the wall directly behind the tub, and will tie the tub drain into the main drain line *downstream* of the toilet drain. The wacky thing about my drain situation is that the vertical drain line runs down an interior wall to the basement, that is in the middle of my bathroom floor, as opposed to a wall that runs continuously between both floors. The toilet's horizontal wet vent is then extended to an offset wall where it extends up to the lav trap arm and then venting up and out the roof.

OK - with all of that background out of the way, my primary question is: Can I use a side inlet elbow (3"x3"x2") where the drain turns into the vertical to head down the wall to the basement? The 2" inlet would serve the tub drain, and the 3" inlet would serve the toilet drain and horizontal wet vent (lav). I've attached an isometric drawing (my first one, so hopefully it makes sense) to describe my plan.

[image]

Comment: From the link http://forms.iapmo.org/email_marketing/codespotlight/2017/Jun15.htm, it appears that this situation is not permitted in UPC, but perhaps it is allowed in IPC?